# Syntax to assign values to struct pointer

Tags: c, struct

I have a quick question about the syntax and the code.

I just found out a way to declare the struct in C which is a bit different from what I've seen so far.

This is the sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct student {
    int age;
    int grade;
    char* name;
};
int main () {
    struct student s = { .name = "Max", .age = 15, .grade = 8 };
    return 0;
}
```

Assigning variables as .var_name works fine and you can assign it in any order you'd like. I liked this approach so I started experimenting and thus hit the wall.
If I were to declare:

```
struct student *s = { ->name = "Max", ->age = 15, ->grade = 8 };
```

This won't work. Is there any syntax that could give the same results when using a pointer as the code above?

Thanks!

Comment: Any chance of allocating memory for the contents of `s`?

Comment: A pointer is not a struct. It just points somewhere else, to an existing struct. Where do you want your `s` to point to?

Comment: When I allocate the memory like this:
      struct student *s = malloc(sizeof (s));
This doesn't allow me to use s = { } kind of initialisation. It's always error.

Comment: Melpomene, so I need to declare struct student *stud = &s; for it to work? I cannot latter change the value of stud from there?

Comment: Note that `sizeof(s)` is not the correct size, it's the size of the *pointer itself*, not what it points to. You need to use `sizeof *s`.

Comment: As for your problem, you initialize the variable you have of the type it is. If you have a structure *object* you can initialize it (like shown in the first example), but if you have a pointer to something you must initialize it as a pointer (i.e. make it point to something). There's no way to do both simultaneously.

Comment: Some programmer dude, when I do: struct student *s = malloc(sizeof (*s));
I am able to use: s->age = 15; s->grade = 8; But is there a way to declare it like struct student s = { .name = "Max", .age = 15, .grade = 8 }; in one line? When there are a lot of variables it makes more sense for me to type it like that. P.S. also malloc(sizeof(s)) doesn't seem to make any problems. The same assignments work. EDIT: Okay, I understand. Thanks! :)

Comment: Regarding the `sizeof` issue. if you're on a 64 bit system then pointers are 8 bytes, your structure is at least 16 bytes. If you use `sizeof s` then you allocate to little memory, and any access outside of that memory will lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (which sometimes *seems* to work, but in the next moment will fail  horribly).

Comment: Aha, didn't know that. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, you can't "assign values to a pointer". A pointer only stores a single value, which is the address of an already existing object.

If you have a pointer pointing to an existing struct variable, you can just initialize that:

```
struct student s = { .name = "Max", .age = 15, .grade = 8 };
struct student *p = &s;
```

If you want to use dynamic memory allocation, things get a bit tricker:

```
struct student *p = malloc(sizeof *p);
if (!p) {
    ...
}
```

`malloc` gives you uninitialized memory, and you cannot use initializer syntax with existing objects.

But you can use a trick involving compound literals (available since C99):

```
*p = (struct student){ .name = "Max", .age = 15, .grade = 8 };
```

Here we use a compound literal to create a new unnamed struct object whose contents we then copy into `*p`.

The same feature can be used to get rid of `s` in the first example:

```
struct student *p = &(struct student){ .name = "Max", .age = 15, .grade = 8 };
```

But in this version `p` still points to automatic memory (like a local variable).

Comment: Aye! Thanks, melpomene! This trick works! :) Thank you for the detailed explanation and the problems that occur using the trick! :) Cheers, mate! :)